# How can I get the real-time video from monitor by FFmpeg in julia?

Tags: video, julia

I did it in Python. But I don't know how to do in Julia. Thanks.

This is my code in Python:

```
pip install ffmpy

from ffmpy import FFmpeg

ff=FFmpeg(
    inputs={"rtsp://......@.....":None},
    outputs={'./Video.mp4':'-t 00:01:00'})

print(ff.cmd)
ff.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Julia translation of your Python Code:

```
using PyCall
run(`$(PyCall.python) -m pip install ffmpy`)
ffmpy = pyimport("ffmpy")
ff=ffmpy.FFmpeg(
    inputs=Dict("rtsp://......@....."=>nothing),
    outputs=Dict("./Video.mp4"=>"-t 00:01:00"))
println(ff.cmd)
ENV["PATH"]="PATH/TO/ffmpeg.executable;"*ENV["PATH"]
ff.run()
```

Comment: Sorry! I didn't post complete code. I edited my questions. That is my complete code. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry sir. I worked this code. I wrote 5 minutes, but the result showed 4:38. What this code need to add?

Comment: @WendyChen I think that this is question about ffmpgeg executable not Julia.

Comment: If I used VideoIO. What I need to add or change?

Comment: I believe you can find the tutorial here: https://juliaio.github.io/VideoIO.jl/stable/reading/